# Exploding gradients with long time series LSTMs

Tags: keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I am trying to train a time series prediction model with a lookback around 100 steps. However, when I first started to train it, the loss was always nan. I wanted to take a closer look and saw that even the first prediction (before any learning, probably with the randomly initialized weights), all of the values are NaN. If I reduce number of lookbacks, then it barely comes around 1e+36, which is still super high, and causing exploding gradients (I guess, still not super familiar with the terms.)

Here is how my architecture looks in code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_features, n_steps), data_format='channels_first')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5, data_format='channels_first')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(outputs.shape[1]))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
```

And the shapes, you can see from the following:
[image: model]

input data consists of some precipitation (around 50-150), temperature (between -10 and 25) and groundwater level data (between 100-500), and output consists of the prediction of groundwater level data.

It seemed to me very weird to have nans or very high numbers without even any training, and I am not sure if this is called exploding gradients, I would like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: have you tried scaling your X and y ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani yes I did (min-max scaling), and it works fine, except in actual predictions I do not know how it is going to capture the values that can higher or lower than the min-max of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you normalize your outputs in range (0., 1.) and use sigmoid in the last layer.

You can always use an inverse transform to reconstruct the original outputs.

```
mn = np.min(y_train)
mx = np.max(y_train)
y_train = (y_train - mn)/(mx - mn)

# ... train

# inverse transform
y_train_original = y_train*(mx-mn) + mn
```

Your last layer is `linear` and previous activation is `relu`. You need to clip the output with `sigmoid`.

1. Normalize your outputs to `0-1` range.
2. Use sigmoid in last layer.
   `model.add(Dense(outputs.shape[1], activation = 'sigmoid'))`

Comment: normalized my output, and tried to do a sigmoid transformation at dense layer, however it did not work again. I guess the values coming from LSTM are very big. Therefore I put a sigmoid on LSTM and left the relu at dense, ans first prediction (without any learning) looks okay, however even after 1 step of fitting, it is nan again.I fail to see what is happening here.

Comment: Then, check your data. Maybe there is some inconsistency there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you first to remove these three lines to see how your models works:

```
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_features, n_steps), data_format='channels_first')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5, data_format='channels_first')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
```